# jQuery hide table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following jQuery script which hides/expands row in table:

it was inspired by this example:

http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/examples/expandable-rows/

```
<script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#orders tr:odd").addClass("odd");
    $("#orders tr:not(.odd)").hide();
    $("#orders tr:first-child").show();

    $("#orders tr.odd").click(function(){
        $(this).next("tr").toggle();
        $(this).find(".toggler").toggleClass("on");
        $(this).find(".toggler").text("hide");

    });
});

</script>
```

My HTML is the following:

```
<table class="blueWrapperTbl" id="orders">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>  <h:outputText value="#{order.orderId}" /> </td>
      <td>  <h:outputText value="#{order.orderId}" /> </td>
      <td>  <h:outputText value="#{order.orderId}" /> </td>
      <td>  <h:outputText value="#{order.orderId}" /> </td>
      <td><a href="#" class="ubber"><b>Change Order</b></a></td>
      <td><a href="#" class="toggler">Show</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    ...
    </tr> 
</table>
```

The relevant CSS parts is the following:

```
.blueWrapperTbl .toggler { background:url(../images/plus.gif) right center no-repeat; padding-right:20px; display:inline-block; text:'fff'}
.blueWrapperTbl .toggler.on { background:url(../images/minus.gif) right center no-repeat; }
```

I need to do the following:

1. When my row is expended I would like to change 'toggler' text from 'Show' to 'hide'.
2. When my row is hidden I dont need to show 'Change order' URL. It must be hidden.

Please help me.

Comment: Wheres the rest of the table? "..." and also whats <h:outputText.... is this some kind of templating system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toggle()` and `toggleClass()` functions are convenience functions that make it easier to do simple things... but they are limited.

Rather than use `toggleClass()`, you might consider using an `if` to check to see if the element has the 'on' class.  If it does, remove that class and change the text to 'Show'.  If it doesn't, add the 'on' class and change the text to 'Hide'.

Rather than using `toggle()`, you could check for the visibility of the row.  If it's visible, hide it and hide the 'Change order' URL.  If it's not visible, show it and show the 'Change order' URL.

Here's a notional example:

```
$('#orders td a')
    .each(function(){
        if( $(this).hasClass('on') ) {
            $(this).removeClass('on');
            // do other things
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('on');
            // do other things
        }
    }
;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. Could you please help me with the code to see if the <a> tag on 'on' class?

Comment: Sure, `$('a.on')` will return all 'a' tags with the 'on' class.  You can also use  `if( $(this).hasClass('on') ) { /* operations */ }` in a `$('a').each()` block.  If you do the latter, then you can easily have an 'else' clause, letting you operate separately on 'a' tags with the 'on' class and those without.

Answer (score 0):

1) Instead of

```
$(this).find(".toggler").text("hide");
```

use

```
$(this).find(".toggler").html("hide");
```

2) Add this to your click handler function

```
$(this).find(".ubber").toggle();
```